The error of quantum adiabatic evolution
In this article about Grover's algorithm in AQC, the author mentions that the system is prepared in the ground state $|{E_0,0}\rangle$ at $t=0$ and evolves under the time-dependent Hamiltonian $H(t)$ from $t=0$ to $t=T$. We denote:

$E_k(t)$ is the $k$-th eigenvalue of $H(t)$ at time $t$
$g_\text{min}=\operatorname{min}_{0\leq t\leq T}[E_1(t)-E_0(t)]$
$D_\text{max}=\operatorname{max}_{0\leq t\leq T}|\langle E_1,t|\frac{\mathrm{d}H(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}|E_0,t\rangle|$

Then in the article, it turns that we have:
$$|\langle E_0,T|\psi(T)\rangle|^2 \geq 1-\varepsilon^2$$
provided that
$$\frac{D_\text{max}}{{g_\text{min}}^2}\leq\varepsilon.$$
How can we get this conclusion? I can't find this in textbooks or articles.
